# Yammer API - Modify text in group info section

Tags: rest, yammer

I need to update text in Info tab in Yammer group using REST API but I can't find any information about such possibilities. In code of the Yammer website I found this link:

`https://www.yammer.com/<myNetwork>/groups/<groupId>/infos/<id>.json`

but I don't know how to get this *id* and what is the parameter name for sending info to this endpoint.

Link to the info tab is: `https://www.yammer.com/<myNetwork>/#/groups/<groupId>/info`

Is it possible to update group info via Yammer API (even though it is not supported)?

Answer (score 1):

This type of operation isn't supported. Yammer group creation and updates are human actions, and automating these are not supported by design.

Comment: I think you're wrong. Yammer API provides endpoints to manage groups (you can read about it here: [link](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/tiabas/yammer-client/Yammer/Api/Group), although there is no word about it in official documentation. But it works :)

Comment: So I guess that updating group info is possible too - I found an endpoint with .json but I don't know how to get to it.

Comment: That's not a supported library and it uses unsupported endpoints.

Comment: So I hope there is an unsupported endpoint for managing group info :)
Thank you for your replies.